# Есть ли аналог функции Buffer.BlockCopy из c# в js или ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть ли аналог функции Buffer.BlockCopy из c# в js или ts

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/slice не оно ?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromarraybuffer-byteoffset-length